# Mocking axios in a vue3 typescript unit test using jest and vue-test-utils2 (Solved)

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, axios, vue-test-utils

My component calls

```
this.axios.get()
```

when being mounted and passes a vuex-store variable to the api. The api returns an array as the response and the component displays some of the returned data after exchanging a loading-element with the real content.

In my unit test I want to simulate the result of the axios-request, wait for the transition between the loading- and the content-element and then finally check the validity of the content. However, the test fails and outputs:

```
Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

and highlights the get on this.axios.

**Here is what I'm expecting to work ([based on this guide](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/v2/guide/http-requests.html#a-list-of-blog-posts)):**

```js
... some imports etc. ...
const mockAxios = { whatIExpectToGet  };
jest.mock("axios", () => ({
  get: jest.fn(() => mockAxios)
}));
it("description of the test", async () => {
  const wrapper = mount(MyComponent);
... code continues ...
```

Of course I'm accesssing axios via this and not directly like they do in the guide. But, since I can't find any mention of anything related to that, I assume that's irrelevant?

**I also tried to mock axios myself like so:**

```js
... imports etc. ...
const axios = {
  get: Promise.resolve({ whatIExpectToGet })
};
it("description of the test", async () => {
  const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
    global: {
      mocks: [ axios ]
    }
  });
... code continues ...
```

Apparently people with similar problems used localVue.use() to inject stuff, [but that's no longer supported](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#no-more-createlocalvue).

Could someone be so kind and smart as to point me into the right direction, please?
Thank you.

***-------------------> SOLUTION <-------------------***

Thanks to [tony 19](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6277151/tony19) this question is already solved.

I ended up using an async function to mock axios because `Promise.resolve()` wasn't working for me:

```
import { shallowMount, flushPromises } from "@vue/test-utils";
import MyComponent from "@/components/MyComponent.vue";

describe("MyComponent.vue", () => {
  const axios = {
    get: async () => ({
      data: { expectedData }
    })
  };
  it("test description", async () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, {
      global: {
        mocks: {
          axios: axios
        }
      }
    } as any);
    expect(wrapper.html()).toContain("some_string_i_display_while_loading");
    await flushPromises();
    expect(wrapper.html()).toContain("some_string_i_display_after_getting_the_response");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`global.mocks`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/v2/api/#global-mocks) to mock `axios` is the right approach, but your attempt incorrectly used an array when it should've been an object:

```js
const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
  global: {
    // mocks: [ axios ] ❌
    mocks: { axios } ✅
  }
})
```

Note `axios.get()` resolves to an `axios.Response` object, which stores the response data in its `data` property, so your mock should do the same.

Here's a full example:

```js
// MyComponent.vue
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.axios.get('foo').then(resp => this.foo = resp.data)
  }
}

// MyComponent.spec.js
it('gets foo', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
    global: {
      mocks: {
        axios: {
          get: Promise.resolve({ data: { foo: true }})

          // OR use an async function, which internally returns a Promise
          get: async () => ({ data: { foo: true }})
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```